# Konsole terminal closes immediately because it cannot locate system icons

Tags: 22.04, kde, qt, konsole

I have Konsole (terminal) version 21.12.3 installed on Ubuntu 22.04 from the Software Centre.

My monitor didn't detect the signal, so I had to do a forced restart.

After restarting, Konsole had much smaller font. As soon as I pressed a key, Konsole closed. It doesn't matter which key. It closes immediately.

I uninstalled, reinstalled but same thing.

I'm looking at the system log and I see Konsole logged these:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
kf.windowsystem: Could not find any platform plugin
Icon theme "breeze" not found.
konsole: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5
```

Obviously the cause. How do I fix these?

Comment: Did you try exporting `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` before running Konsole? `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland`

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I just put that in my bashrc, opened Konsole but same small font and closed once I press a key.

Comment: Can you try an Xorg session? Log out, and in the bottom right you should have the option to use either Xorg or Wayland. Select Xorg and log back in.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Okay, just done. Unfortunately I get the same problem.

Comment: It sounds like you half-know the problem? Is it possible I re-install whatever has got corrupted?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea about the problem. I just googled the warning. :P Do you use an NVIDIA graphics card? Because [this similar issue](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/18316), albeit for qbittorrent, suggests using the NVIDIA driver instead of the Nouveau one as a workaround.

Comment: Another suggestion: Can you create a new user and see if konsole works there? If it works, that means that it's an issue with your user, so there should be some config in your home that causes the issue.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Same thing happens. I'm a bit concerned this happened so easily.... from a forced restart....

Comment: Just had another symptom. I went to run Git difftool, which for me is P4V/P4Merge. I got this error: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Comment: It looks like it has an empty path when it says could not find the qt platform plugin wayland in ""

Comment: Hmmm... Is this of any help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598099/could-not-find-the-qt-platform-plugin-wayland

Comment: Also, since you did a force restart, may also try running `fsck`, preferably from a Live USB. See here how to do it: https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Ah, only just saw this. I just finished a complete re-install and manually installing all my packages/repos, wasting time. Do you know simplest way to create an OS Image? I'm quite worried how easily Linux breaks from a forced restart.

Comment: [Timeshift](https://teejeetech.com/timeshift/) perhaps? All systems can break if they are not restarted/shut down correctly. `fsck` could fix many of the issues that occurred from force-restarting.